# Aggregation on updating order data in Druid

Tags: druid

I have streaming data using Kafka to Druid. It's an eCommerce de-normalized order event data where status and few fields get updated in every event.
I need to do aggregate query based on timestamp with the most updated entry only.

For example: If data sample is:

> {"orderId":"123","status":"Initiated","items":"item","qty":1,"paymentId":null,"shipmentId":null,timestamp:"2021-03-05T01:02:33Z"}
> {"orderId":"abc","status":"Initiated","items":"item","qty":1,"paymentId":null,"shipmentId":null,timestamp:"2021-03-05T01:03:33Z"}
> {"orderId":"123","status":"Shipped","items":"item","qty":1,"paymentId":null,"shipmentId":null,timestamp:"2021-03-07T02:03:33Z"}

Now if I want to query on all orders stuck on "Initiated" status for more than 2 days then for above data it should only show orderId "abc".
But if I query something like

```
Select orderId,qty,paymentId from order where status = Initiated and WHERE "timestamp" < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

This query will return both orders "123" and "abc", but 123 has another event received after 2 days so the previous events should not be included in result.

Is their any good and optimized way to handle this kind of scenarios in Apache druid?

One way I was thinking to use a separate lookup table to store orderId and latest status and perform a join with this lookup and above aggregation query on orderId and status

EDIT 1:
This query works but it joins on whole table, which can give resource limit  exception for big datasets:

```
WITH maxOrderTime (orderId, "__time") AS
(
SELECT orderId, max("__time") FROM inline_data
   GROUP BY orderId
)
SELECT inline_data.orderId FROM inline_data 
JOIN maxOrderTime
ON inline_data.orderId = maxOrderTime.orderId
AND inline_data."__time" = maxOrderTime."__time"
WHERE inline_data.status='Initiated' and inline_data."__time" < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

EDIT 2:
Tried with:

```
SELECT
  inline_data.orderID,
  MAX(LOOKUP(status, 'status_as_number')) as last_status
FROM inline_data
WHERE
  inline_data."__time" < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY inline_data.orderID
HAVING last_status = 1
```

But gives this error:

> Error: Unknown exception
>
> Error while applying rule DruidQueryRule(AGGREGATE), args
> [rel#1853:LogicalAggregate.NONE.,
> rel#1863:DruidQueryRel.NONE.[](query={"queryType":"scan","dataSource":{"type":"table","name":"inline_data"},"intervals":{"type":"intervals","intervals":["-146136543-09-08T08:23:32.096Z/2021-03-14T09:57:05.000Z"]},"virtualColumns":[{"type":"expression","name":"v0","expression":"lookup("status",'status_as_number')","outputType":"STRING"}],"resultFormat":"compactedList","batchSize":20480,"order":"none","filter":null,"columns":["orderID","v0"],"legacy":false,"context":{"sqlOuterLimit":100,"sqlQueryId":"fbc167be-48fc-4863-b3a8-b8a7c45fb60f"},"descending":false,"granularity":{"type":"all"}},signature={orderID:LONG,
> v0:STRING})]
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done easier. If you replace the status to a numeric representation, you can use it more easy.

First use an inline lookup to replace the status. See this page how to define a lookup: https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.20.1/querying/lookups.html

Now, we have for example these values in a lookup named `status_as_number`:

```
Initiated = 1
Shipped = 2
```

Since we now have a numeric representation, you can simply do a group by query and see the max status number. A query like this would be sufficient:

```
SELECT
  inline_data.orderId,
  MAX(LOOKUP(status, 'status_as_number')) as last_status
FROM inline_data
WHERE
  inline_data."__time" < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY inline_data.orderId
HAVING last_status = 1
```

Note: this query is not tested. The HAVING part makes sure that you only see orders which are Initiated.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: If you do not want to use a lookup, you can also use a simple case statement. For example:

`MAX( CASE status WHEN 'Initiated' THEN 1 WHEN 'Shipped' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END ) as last_status`

I think this should also work...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried with the query and it threw a runtime exception. I have added the error in question. Any idea on this? Thanks

Comment: `'WHERE inline_data."__time" < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)' `This line have a problem, it will only take events received before 2 days. So if an `orderID` was initiated initially but received a `Shipped` event later(within last 2 days) then it will still include the `orderID` in result

Comment: Please try with double quotes around all field and table names, LIKE: 
`SELECT
  "inline_data"."orderId",
  MAX(LOOKUP("status", 'status_as_number')) as last_status
FROM "inline_data"
WHERE
  "inline_data"."__time" < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY "inline_data"."orderId"
HAVING last_status = 1`

I assume that the Initiated is always before the Shipped state. So if the Initiated state is before the 2 days window, and the Shipped state is, the order will NOT be in the result. This is because the "max" state still is the "shipped" state (2) and will be filtered out.

Comment: hi, thanks for the explanation, one more question, would it be possible to change it to count query? `SELECT COUNT(*) from (
SELECT
  inline_data.orderID,
 LATEST(LOOKUP(status, 'status_as_number')) as last_status
FROM inline_data
WHERE
  inline_data."__time" < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY inline_data.orderID
HAVING last_status = 1)`

I did this but this might not be the best way

Comment: hi, thanks for the explanation, one more question, would it be possible to change it to count query? `SELECT COUNT(*) from ( SELECT   inline_data.orderID,  LATEST(LOOKUP(status, 'status_as_number')) as last_status FROM inline_data WHERE   inline_data."__time" < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) GROUP BY inline_data.orderID HAVING last_status = 1)` I did this but it's causing `Resource limit exceeded error` as it's trying to count on all the rows possible while keeping them in memory. I have around ~10M records

Comment: I assume you want to count the number of orders which are still initial. In that case, you could do something like this: ```SELECT COUNT( distinct  inline_data.orderID ) FROM inline_data WHERE   inline_data."__time" < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) GROUP BY inline_data.orderID HAVING LATEST(LOOKUP(status, 'status_as_number')) = 1``` . Not tested though